# Unable to import module appengine.ext

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am playing with ndb, but I am stuck when I import the appengine module in python. This happens only in my unit tests. Unit tests are located in test.py at the root of the project.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from google.appengine.ext import ndb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named appengine.ext
```

The following are the contents of my .bash_profile relevant to the above.

```
APP_ENGINE_HOME="/Users/xxxxx/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/"
export PATH=$PATH:$MYSQL:$M2_HOME/bin:$ANT_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin:$APP_ENGINE_HOME
```

I have a directory called Google in google_appengine with the following structure

```
.Gooogle
+-- __init__.py
+-- appengine
|   +-- __init__.py
|   +-- ext
    |   +-- ndb
    |   +-- __init__.py
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to use the appengine packages outside of it is to make use of dev_appserver to do the setup:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/google_appengine')
import dev_appserver
dev_appserver.fix_sys_path()

# and then e.g.
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however I am still getting the same error. "ImportError: No module named appengine.ext"

Answer (score 0):

Is the name of the folder `google` exactly? Your question seems to show it as `.Gooogle`...?

`__init__.py` is used by the interpreter when scanning the PYTHONPATH (which can be set as an environment variable like PATH, or modified in code using patterns similar to what the other user included in their answer), attempts to find folders containing an `__init__.py`, and considers these to be modules. Subfolders with their own `__init__.py` are also considered submodules, etc...

If PYTHONPATH includes the folder that has `google`, which contains `__init__.py` and folders like `appengine`, it should be import-ready in your code. Can you try to run the following and post the output? This will show what directories are in your PYTHONPATH.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```